# "Cannot read property of 'setMap' of undefined" when trying to remove markers in GoogleMaps component (Vue)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I'm trying to remove markers from my map every time I fetch new results from the API. I want to do this so that the markers from the previous fetch won't be on the map. I read the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove), it states to iterate through the markers and use the "setMap(null)" function on each marker to remove that marker from the map. I keep getting the "Cannot read property of 'setMap' of undefined" in the Chrome dev console.

The following code is how I'm trying to remove the markers, and is very similar to what the Google Maps API documentation is doing, except I'm not using multiple functions. Instead, I just check if the array holding the markers is not null, then I try to remove the markers and set the array holding the markers to null.

```
watch: {
    async events() {
        try {
            const google = await gMaps();

            if(this.locations !== null) {
                for(let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
                    this.locations[i].setMap(null);
                }

                this.locations = [];
            }

            this.locations = this.events.map(event => {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: parseInt(event.latitude, 10),
                        lng: parseInt(event.longitude, 10)
                    },
                    map: this.map,
                    title: event.title
                })
            })
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The following is all of the code inside of the script tag in my Google Maps component.

```
import gMaps from '../lib/gMaps.js'

export default {
    name: 'GoogleMaps',
    props: {
        events: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            map: null,
            locations: []
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        try {
            const google = await gMaps();
            const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el);

            geocoder.geocode({ address: 'USA'}, (results, status) => {
                if (status !== 'OK' || !results[0]) {
                    throw new Error(status);
                }

                this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                this.map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        async events() {
            try {
                const google = await gMaps();

                if(this.locations !== null) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
                        this.locations[i].setMap(null);
                    }

                    this.locations = [];
                }

                this.locations = this.events.map(event => {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: {
                            lat: parseInt(event.latitude, 10),
                            lng: parseInt(event.longitude, 10)
                        },
                        map: this.map,
                        title: event.title
                    })
                })
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `locations` array is not empty, but filled with `undefined` elements (e.g. `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`).

Since `locations` is populated in `this.locations = this.events.map(...)`, the problem must be there.

And it is. As `.map()` argument, you are using an arrow function with `{}`s and not returning anything.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
this.locations = this.events.map(event => {
    new google.maps.Marker(...)
    return undefined;
})
```

**Fix:** You have two options: use the shorter version (without braces) or add a `return` statement.

Removing the braces:

```
            this.locations = this.events.map(event => // { removed
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lat: parseInt(event.latitude, 10),
                        lng: parseInt(event.longitude, 10)
                    },
                    map: this.map,
                    title: event.title
                })
            ) // was: })
```

Or adding a return:

```
            this.locations = this.events.map(event => {
                return new google.maps.Marker({      // added return here
                    position: {
                        lat: parseInt(event.latitude, 10),
                        lng: parseInt(event.longitude, 10)
                    },
                    map: this.map,
                    title: event.title
                })
            })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm fairly new to Javascript, so I'm still learning the ins and outs of the syntax.